# How to display a custom message for no results found in an Advanced widget search, IDX Broker?

Tags: idx

I am building a real estate website http://www.tampatogulfhomes.com using IDX Broker Plugin.
I want to display a custom message if no results found when searched using Advanced Search Widget. For Example: [Lagomar | Access Realty](http://tampatogulfhomes.com/homes-sale-hillsborough-county-tampa-mls-real-estate-listings/apollo-beach-homes-sale/lagomar/) (http://tampatogulfhomes.com/homes-sale-hillsborough-county-tampa-mls-real-estate-listings/apollo-beach-homes-sale/lagomar/), return no result and wat to display a message to the user.
Please can someone tell how can I implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript to write to the DOM when the element id "IDX-noResultsMessage" is present. This ID only appears when there are no properties returned in a search results page.

There are online tutorials at the [IDX Broker developers site](https://developers.idxbroker.com)

Here is a bit of sample code:

```
var searchResults = document.getElementById('IDX-noResultsMessage');
if(searchResults !== null)
{
document.getElementById('IDX-noResultsMessage').innerHTML='Add your custom message here';
}
```

Comment: I cannot find any ID with the name "IDX-noResultsMessage" in the DOM. What I see in the DOM something related to this is:  
/* <![CDATA[ */
var uiAutocompleteL10n = {"noResults":"No results found.","oneResult":"1 result found. Use up and down arrow keys to navigate.","manyResults":"%d results found. Use up and down arrow keys to navigate.","itemSelected":"Item selected."};
/* ]]> */
Is there any way I can fetch this value and display in DOM? Here is the link: http://accessrealtytampa.com/homes-sale-hillsborough-county-tampa-mls-real-estate-listings/apollo-beach_fl/sunset-bay-townhomes/

Comment: The link provided is not an IDX Broker search results page. So the ID is not present. You can find that ID on an IDX page. Like this results http://homes.accessrealtytampa.com/idx/results/listings?idxID=b003&pt=all&lp=200000&hp=1&bd=1&tb=100&ccz=city&widgetReferer=true

Comment: Yes, Is there any way to display a custom message for the Showcase widget, if no listings are rendered?

Comment: You could look for the empty div and if the innerHTML has nothing in it then write your message. Like:

`<div id="IDX-showcaseGallery-12345" class="IDX-showcaseWrapper"></div>`

This will simply be empty. If you want to be specific to a widget you will need to use the ID, but if you want to reuse your code you could use the class to select. Either way, you will need to run your code after the JS for the widget runs. This could be a setTimeout() or a check for a particular element to have been loaded first.